# Node.JS Express API - Promise Chain including Request-Promise chain - ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN

Tags: node.js, api, express, promise, request-promise

The chain I have is retrieving information from a Sql Server and then setting up the data to then be sent to an api via post. The problem is i receive this **RequestError** message, **"TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["key"]"

**Objective**

-Retrieve Data using id 
-Format data 
-Send new, separate request to an api with formatted data 
-Resolve results returned from api call

**router.js**

```js
    router.get('/request/:id', controller.data_post)
    module.exports = router
```

**Controller.js**

```js
    exports.data_post = function(req, res) {

        ...

        RetrieveData( req.id ) //retrieves data
        .then( results => { //format data

           var obj = formatData(results);
           let body = [];
           body.push(obj);

           return body //resolve formatted data
         } //End Of Promise
        })
       .then( body => { //Send new, separate request to an api with formatted data

             var options = :{
                 method: 'POST',
                 uri: 'url',
                 headers: {
                     'key':'value',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 },
                 body: JSON.stringify(body),
                 json:true
         }

         return option
         })
        .then( results => {
          //send results
        })
        .catch( error => {
         //error routine
        }) 
    }
```

**RetrieveData.js**

```js
    function RetrieveData( id ){
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         ...
         resolve(data)
      }
      return promise;
    }
```

**RequestUtility.js**

```js
    const request = require('request-promise')

    function requestutility(options) {
       return request(options)
       .then( response => {
           return response;
       }) 
       .catch( error => {
          return error;
        })
    }
```

**Current Error**

- **"name"**: "RequestError",
- **message"**: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_HTTP_TOKEN]: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["key"]",
- **option**s: Object{},
- **callback**: function RP$callback(err, response, body) {

  - **arguments**:TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
  - **caller**:TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems I see here

- You don't need to return Promise.resolve and Promise.reject in the request utility method. Since request promise returns a promise, your promise will be resolved when succesfull and rejected when error. So you can get rid of requestutility alltogether.
- You are wrapping results in `new Promise` which is not required.
- `resolve( requestutility(option))` doesn't work the way you are expecting it to work as it will resolve to a promise instead of value.
- Remove the key from headers.
  I have tried to update the code. It should look like

```
const request = require("request-promise");

RetrieveData(id)
  .then(results => {
    const obj = formatData(results);
    const body = [];
    body.push(obj);
    return body;
  })
  .then(body => {
    const options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "uri": "url",
      "headers": {
        "key": "value",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify(body),
      "json": true
    };

    return request(options);
  })
  .then(results => {
    // send results
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // error routine
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I updated the code to look like that. Unfortunately, still getting the area but the syntax suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: can you also add you route definition from where you are calling this method?

Comment: try removing key from headers

Comment: Looks like that key is the problem...Good find! I guess i have to find another way to use the key. I receive an unauthorized statusCode so that's progress. Thank you!

Comment: glad it helped.

Comment: If that answer help you, dont forget to mark as right answer.